# Acces control using SVN "authz" and svnserve

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svnserve, authz

I have a SVN server running on Windows

I create a repo for a project like this:

E:\SVN\WEB\MYWEB-WWW

I add in the "passwd" file the users:

```
[users]
admin      = qazwsx 
developer1 = 123456
developer2 = qwerty
```

then I edit the "authz" file:

```
[groups]
Admins = admin
Developers = developer1, developer2

[/]
@Admins = rw
@Developers = r
* =
```

my "svnserve.conf" file looks like this:

```
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
auth-access = read

password-db = passwd

authz-db = authz
```

I check out the repo, and login with admin user and everything is fine, but when I try to do a commit with admin user it fails showing this message "Authentication failed"

I also tried without the groups using the "admin" user but the same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My gut feeling is that your svnserver.conf file has the extra `auth-access = read` line, and that's causing you problems.

Normally, if you set `auth-access = write`, it implies read too. You don't list the line twice to get both read and write access.

Think of it this way: What `svnserve.conf` giveth, `authz` file taketh away. In other words, you grant your authorized users read/write access via the `auth-access = write`. Then, you can limit that access via your `authz` file. However, if you don't grant the right in `svnserve.conf` in the first place, you can't grant that right in `authz`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that was the problem ;D

Answer (score 0):

In additional , "auth-access" is not the default right but the highest right authed users have.